# Remove characters before the last blank, convert result to DATE from NVARCHAR

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, nvarchar

I receive an Excel spreadsheet monthly with a cell containing both comments and a date in the same cell.  I import the spreadsheet to a SQL table and need to extract the last 8-10 characters (the date) and convert them from NVARCHAR to DATE format.

**Example:**
    **From this:** *Active/No Address 4/11/2016*
    **To this:** *2016/04/11*

The biggest challenge I'm having is that the numbers representing the month and date are not fixed length, they could be either one or two characters.  Single character days or months do not have a leading zero.

I have tried every combination of CHARINDEX, RIGHT(), LEFT(), REPLACE, and SUBSTRING I could think of without any success.

Assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Very sorry, I failed to include this as well.  The text preceding the date is also variable in length.  The "Active/No Address" prefix changes as well.

Comment: **_Final Solution:_**  REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE, RIGHT(ColumnName,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(ColumnName),0)), 110), '-','/') AS Alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I would go with is reversing the string, finding the first space, and then formatting that chunk of text.  This code works for multiple cases with single value months and days and it will not be impacted by the length of the text before the date.

```
Declare @1 VARCHAR(50) = 'Active/No Address 4/11/2016'
Declare @2 VARCHAR(50) = 'Active/No Address 9/3/2016'
Declare @3 VARCHAR(50) = 'Active/No Address 12/31/2016'

SELECT 


 REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE, RIGHT(@1,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@1),0)), 110), '-','/')
, REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE, RIGHT(@2,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@2),0)), 110), '-','/')
, REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE, RIGHT(@3,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@3),0)), 110), '-','/')
```

Comment: 110 is mm-dd-yyyy ...  did you mean 101 (mm/dd/yyyy)?

Comment: Hmm when I execute my code, it appears as yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: once you've converted it to a datetime, the final display is up to the UI. The original question was to only make it into a datetime, so frankly I think your original version was "right" - the number there had nothing to do with what was appearing on your screen (that's just the client UI)

Comment: It showed up just fine as yyyy/mm/dd which is what I wanted.  I'm selecting this as the best answer since it was the first answer which led me to the solution.  I dropped the DECLARE statements and the final solution was this.  REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE, RIGHT(**ColumnName**,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(**ColumnName**),0)), 110), '-','/') AS **Alias**

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
declare @text nvarchar(max) = 'Active/No Address 4/11/2016';
declare @index int = charindex(' ', reverse(@text)) - 2;
declare @foo nvarchar(max) = substring(@text, len(@text) - @index, @index + 1);
select convert(datetime, @foo, 101)
```